# Padrões de Projeto: Singleton

Tags: c#, design-pattern, singleton

Sei que o `Singleton` me garante uma única instância de um dado objeto. Isso eu entendi. O que me cria dúvida seria seu uso na prática assim. Vamos supor o código abaixo, usando `Singleton` com `Generics`(código tirado da internet).

```
public sealed class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        private static T instance;

        public static T Instance()
        {
            lock (typeof(T))
                if (instance == null) instance = new T();

            return instance;
        }
    }
```

Tenho um formulário de Pedidos onde vou lançar meus pedidos. Vou instanciar minha classe de `Pedidos(T)`? E a conexão com o banco, como eu faço? Essa é a dúvida que tenho ao implementar esse Pattern. Onde entra a conexão com o banco aí?

Comment: pelo que entendo, se usar Singleton para pedidos, toda vez que chamar a classe, será retornado o mesmo pedido... teria q limpar o pedido e fazer outro, pois o a instancia do objeto já vai estar criada. Não vejo nenhum motivo de usar isso para pedidos.

Comment: Primeiramente qual o seu objetivo de utilizar um singleton? Fazer uma conexão com o banco de dados não é recomendado utilizando um singleton, para isso faça uma connection pool.

Comment: É exatamente isso que queria ler. Nesse meu teste, eu preciso implementar pelo menos um Pattern, e pensei no Singleton por achar ser mais simples, mas vejo que não é bem assim. Entendi, lembrando que estou sendo submetido a um teste e tem muita coisa a ser avaliada, entre eles, implementar um pattern.

Comment: Chegou a olhar as perguntas relacionadas ali do lado ---> ?

Comment: @rray, li porque não devemos usar Singleton, do colega **Maniero** e foi muito bem explicada pelo colega **utluiz**. Estou lendo sim, sempre leio quando faço perguntas a respeito de qualquer assunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente nós utilizamos o `Singleton`em uma das seguintes situações:

- A classe consome recursos externos compartilhados
- Queremos evitar o overhead de instanciar a classe em muitos lugares diferentes

Por exemplo, muitas pessoas colocam a conexão com o banco de dados dentro de um `Singleton` para não ter que ficar reconectando com o banco toda vez que executar uma query. Dessa forma, a conexão com o banco é feita 1 única vez e permanece ativa durante todo o ciclo de vida da aplicação.

Outro motivo para utilizar este pattern é quando uma classe será acessada em muitos lugares do sistema e nós não queremos abusar de injeção de dependência. As classes de escrita de logs às vezes são implementadas com `Singleton` para não ter que injetar um objeto de log em todas as classes do sistema.

Vale a pena ressaltar que o `Singleton` é muitas vezes [considerado um antipattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/scottdensmore/2004/05/25/why-singletons-are-evil/), pois pode prejudicar a criação de testes unitários e promove muito acoplamento entre classes (isso é algo ruim na orientação a objetos).